# How can I prevent Firefox from opening the gridview header sort postback link in a new tab on Ctrl Click

Tags: firefox, controls, click, mozilla

I am trying to make my gridview control in ASP.Net do a multi sort based on if the user pressed Ctrl key when trying to sort by clicking on a column name.  The problem is that when I am using Firefox, if I click on a column name with Ctrl key pressed, the browser tries to open "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPla..." link in a new tab.  IE and Chrome both don't do this unless the link is a real link.

Is there a way I can prevent Firefox from opening the link in a new tab and still cause the page to postback normally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the event of the Ctrl key being pushed down, using document.onKeyDown.

In your event handler, check if 'Ctrl' (key code 17) was pressed, as follows:

```
function document_keyDown(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
        if (KeyID == 17) { 
            ctrlDown = true;
        }
}
```

Here, I'm setting a 'ctrlDown' variable to true.

For the onKeyUp event, you can do the exact opposite:

```
function document_keyUp(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if (KeyID == 17) { 
       ctrlDown = false;
    }
}
```

Then, in the click event of your column elements, you can check if Ctrl has been clicked or not:

```
function columnElement_click() {
    if (ctrlDown != undefined && ctrlDown == true)
        alert("Ctrl + Click Received");
    return false;
}
```

Make sure your column click handler **returns false**. Otherwise, the browser will execute the code, but then navigate to the address in the link's 'href' attribute.

Hope this helps.

(See also: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial138_Get-key-press-event-using-JavaScript.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  I will try to implement it.